# MVC 4 form is submitting even when the javascript validation fails

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

For some reason my MVC4 form is submitting even when the java script validation fails. Please see the code below in my view. I do see the javascript alert but form is submitting to the server.

Any ideas what I am missing?

```
@model  DataAccess.Question
```

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Question", new { QuestionId = Model.QuestionId }))
{
    <h2>Survey</h2>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Please Choose</legend>
        <p>
            Question:
            @Model.QuestionId
        </p>
        <p>
            Description:
            @Model.Description
        </p>
        <ul style="list-style:none;">
            @foreach (var item in Model.Answers)
            {
                <li> @Html.RadioButton("ChoiceList", item.score) @item.AnswerDesc</li>

            }
        </ul>


        <input type="submit" value="Next" id="submitButton" onclick="getCheckedRadioButton()" />
    </fieldset>

}
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getCheckedRadioButton() {
    var radio = document.getElementsByName("ChoiceList");
    for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++) {
        if (radio[i].checked) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    alert("Please select an option");      
    return false;
}
 </script>
```

I have also checked my web.config and the following keys are true

```
 <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
 <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Comment: did you try my updated code? Is your form still not working?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and solved adding an attribute to form element. Try this

```
Html.BeginForm(new { onsubmit = "return getCheckedRadioButton();" })
```

with your others attributes

```
Html.BeginForm("Index", "Question", new { QuestionId = Model.QuestionId}, FormMethod.POST, new { onsubmit="return getCheckedRadioButton();"})
```

in this way your form should be rendered with this new attribute

refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460542%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) for documentation

Comment: I have tried the following but it does not work @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Question",new { onsubmit = "return getCheckedRadioButton();" , QuestionId = Model.QuestionId }))

Comment: @Learner try my updated answer and let me know. (second update... try now)